# Find old version of ActiveRecord Oracle adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I'm trying to recreate an old rails server that is now a one-of-a-kind snowflake, and I have to track down all the old versions of gems that it's using.

Where can I find a copy of the activerecord-oracle-adapter gem version 1.0.0.9250? It looks like that gem was replaced by the [activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/releases), and I can find versions of that back to 1.1.1. I can't find any versions of the activerecord-oracle-adapter.

Alternatively, does anyone know of a version of activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter that is compatible with Rails 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found a public source for the gem, but I did manage to copy it from the snowflake server to my workstation. I had to copy a directory and a configuration file:

- `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/activerecord-oracle-adapter-1.0.0.9250`
- `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/specifications/activerecord-oracle-adapter-1.0.0.9250.gemspec`

Comment: Is the "snowflake server" public? Is the gem still there? Or can you post the gem online somewhere? I need a copy of this myself...

Comment: No, @PJSCopeland, we've upgraded since I posted the question, and I don't have the old gems any more.